# Minipage on the first document page

Tags: minipage

I am trying to have a minipage on my first document page in order to color it from below a header to the end of the page. Somehow it seems after a certain minipage length LaTeX jumps to a second page leaves the first one empty and does what I want on the second page. A minimal working exampel is the code below. If you change the vspace value from 21 cm to 25.6 cm the problem I have desrcibed should appear. Or If someone knows a way to not show the empty page in the PDF that would work too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\lhead{\Huge \textbf{Hello}}

\begin{document}

    \fcolorbox{gray}{gray}{
        \begin{minipage}{7.5cm}
     \vspace{21cm} %25.6cm und 21cm
        \end{minipage}
    }
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a text height of 621pt (equivalent to 21.82 cm).
So `\vspace{621pt}` will fit on the first page (you must set `\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt})` while `\vspace{622pt`} will not.

Comment: Thank you I think I will for now follow a different approach